# Rate limiting queued mail in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, rate-limiting

I am attempting to use rate limiting to throttle outgoing mail in a laravel 8 project. I have two mail queues, named `email` and `email2`. I want each queue to limit to 15 emails per minute.

In my AppServiceProvider.php, I have

```
        RateLimiter::for('email', function ($job) {
            return Limit::perMinute(15)->by($job->queue);
        });
```

This is one of my mailables

```
class AuthTokenMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(int $code)
    {
        $this->onQueue('email');
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->text('emails.authtoken');
    }
    
    public function middleware()
    {
        return [new RateLimited('email')];
    }

}
```

But when I run it, there is no throttling. I am still getting >50 emails per minute.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Laravel 6. Did you ever find a solution?